# update table data automatically every year

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql, date

I have a data base table containing a `id, description, start_date, end_date` there are 12 entries for every month i just want to increment year 2012 to 2013 in every `start_date, end_date` field when this year end is it possible when a super user login check date and if it is `01-01-20xx` update year only in database table.

Comment: show how you set this month-year... (in your code)

Comment: why just use the current year, if that's what you want to update to

Comment: what is datatype of start_date and end_date?

Comment: Database have Timestamp option where its counting current day/month/year time.. you can use it...

Comment: i will get the date from database only format of date in database is dd-mm-yyy

Comment: @Svetlio how to use that time stamp option to update year only

Comment: you just tell it to what to update too... check mysql documantation

Comment: @sivagopal If you need only monthes, store month numbers in INT field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query="UPDATE awards_list SET start_date = start_date + interval '1 year', 
            end_date = end_date + interval '1 year'";
```

Iam also using postgressql in that this worked perfectly and i got it through a click button i.e when click on button the entire table year fields will increment by 1 year so one click for one year is enough.

Answer (score 2):

MySql event scheduler Here :

[MySql Event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-overview.html)

Comment: ... and you can use it in MySQL 5.1.6 and later versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
  UPDATE Table_name SET start_date = DATE_ADD(start_date,INTERVAL 1 YEAR), end_date = DATE_ADD(end_date,INTERVAL 1 YEAR) WHERE id = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This       

 <?php
        $currentyear=date("Y");
        //check the year database value 
        $yearindatabase=2012;//from database

        if($currentyear>$yearindatabase)
        {


     for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
        {

        $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i, $currentyear);
        $start_date="2012-".$i."-01";
        $end_date="2012-".$i."-".$num."";

        //Update Query

        $queryUpdate="update table set start_date='".$start_date."',end_date='".$end_date."'";

        }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working

```
 UPDATE Table_name SET start_date = DATE_ADD(start_date,INTERVAL 1 YEAR), end_date = DATE_ADD(end_date,INTERVAL 1 YEAR) WHERE id = '';
```